# redis throws an error even though extension is loaded just fine

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

Its my fifth day trying to fix this on my mac mountain-lion.
I used home brew to install phpredis using this http://www.astonishdesign.com/blog/native-lamp-stack-mac-os-x. By the way home brew was also used to install redis.
My php info shows

```
redis
Redis Support   enabled
Redis Version   2.2.3
```

when I run this code

```
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);

$redis->set('key', 'val');

echo $redis->get('key')
```

;

I get this error

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RedisException' with message 'Redis server went away' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/test/index.php on line 6
    ( ! ) RedisException: Redis server went away in /Library/WebServer/Documents/test/index.php on line 6
```

What am I missing

Comment: Redis 2.2.3 is awfully old.

Comment: I think 2.2.3 refers to Redis extension version, not Redis server.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the Redis Server is running?

If you go to the Mac command line and type redis-cli, do you get a prompt like:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379>
```

If not, your server isn't running. You can start it manually by running `redis-server`, then test your script.

There are probably better ways of running redis server on a mac, but at least you'll know if it's just a matter of starting the server.